# "They are not on/in her side."

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

My siblings and I are watching some Turkish drama on TV and after a scene of a heated discussion, my sister said this:

> Yay! They are not on her side.

Then our mother said:

> IN her side.

So I'm kinda curious which one is right. "In her side" or "on her side"?

Comment: You were *watching some Turkish drama **on TV***, not ***watching TV of** some Turkish drama*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Done.

Comment: Have an upvote for your question! I *think* I can vaguely understand why you might have thought your original version was valid (it *almost* makes sense), but I'm afraid I don't know how to clearly explain exactly why it's not idiomatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be *on her side*.  This phrase is defined in a dictionary, as shown below.

[https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20someone%27s%20side#:~:text=1%20%3A%20supporting%20someone%20in%20his,her%20opinion%2C%20position%2C%20etc](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20someone%27s%20side#:%7E:text=1%20%3A%20supporting%20someone%20in%20his,her%20opinion%2C%20position%2C%20etc).

> on someone's side idiom

> Definition of on someone's side
> 1: supporting someone in his or her opinion, position, etc.
> Are you on my side or his?

Comment: There are valid uses of "in her side", but they have a completely different meaning - eg "He's a thorn in her side", or "She has a stitch in her side".